# Wireless electricity through Wi-Fi power signal?

Tags: electricity, waves

Could there be a method to obtain and send worldwide electricity through WiFi? I mean if we have internet everywhere and only need a WiFi device, can we apply the same to electricity technology? or electrons conducted by WiFi waves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that with "Wi-Fi power", you actually mean a "wireless power grid", and not using you Internet Wi-Fi router to power your cell-phone.

If you want to use actual Wi-Fi devices to power anything, you are out of luck. The energy emmitted by a normal Wi-Fi device is in the order of 1 Watt, top. And the available energy decreases with the square of the distance, so the amount of energy available to charge your mobile phone will be negligible.

If you are talking about [wireless power grids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power), that's another matter. It *can* be done, and experiments have been sucessful, sometimes. It usually involves sending a high energy beam of electromagnetic-radiation (not electrons) between parabolic antannaes. It could be used to bring energy from a space-solar-generator, but I would not install this on my house: imagine that somebody crosses the invisible beam!